# Power BI Embedded Incremental Refresh

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

You can't use incremental refresh in Power BI Embedded. Is there an alternative to incrementally refresh your data in Power BI Embedded? And what about Power BI Embedding?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft POWER BI refresh the data only can do using two methods in-app power bi (web). If refreshed data in power Bi then automatically reflect in Power BI Embedded report. How many ways data can refresh points are given below please read this.

1. Manual refresh
2. Refresh Scheduler

Go on your https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/list/reports and click on action column on the 4th icon click on that after that on popup will be open
[scheduler image icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEEmj.png)
then click on the 3rd icon refresh, it will refresh your data manual.

2. The second method is quite long actually and to understand this you can visit this link. Try now

How To Configure Schedule Refresh In Power BI Reports? - [Loginworks Softwares Pvt. Ltd.](https://www.loginworks.com/blogs/how-to-configure-schedule-refresh-in-power-bi-reports/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can according to the info provided, please see below and if it helps:

**Step 1**: In Power BI desktop, select table where you have applied custom filters and go to its context menu.

**Step 2**: Select an Incremental Refresh option that will pop up an Incremental Refresh window: Select an Incremental refresh table (where you have applied custom filters). Create rows storage policy.